# How could I write a function call once with an nested let in an if-let?

Tags: clojure

I have these functions:

```
(def i (atom {})) ;incremented/calculated file stats

(defn updatei [n fic fos]
  (swap! i conj {(keyword n)[fic fos]}))

(defn calcfo [fo fi fis]
  (if-let [n (get @i fo)] ;find a previous record?
    (let [fic (inc (first n)), fos (+ fis (second n))] ;increment the stats
      (updatei fo fic fos))
    (let [fic 1, fos fis] ;if not then: first calc recorded
      (updatei fo fic fos))))
```

How could I write (updatei fo fic fos) once, instead of having it listed twice in the function? Is there a secret or-let I am unaware of?

-Hypothetical code-

```
(defn calcfo [fo fi fis]
  (if-let [n (get @i fo)] ;find a previous record?
    (let [fic (inc (first n)), fos (+ fis (second n))] ;increment the stats
    (or-let [fic 1, fos fis] ;if not then: first calc recorded
      (updatei fo fic fos)))))
```

Or am I thinking of this too imperatively versus functionally?

EDIT:

I decided this made the most sense to me:

```
(defn calcfo [fo fis]
  (apply updatei fo
  (if-let [[rfc rfos] (get @i fo)] ;find a previous record?
       [(inc rfc) (+ rfos fis)] ;increment the stats
       [1 fis]) ;if not then: first calc recorded
      ))
```

Thanks for the great answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A rearrangement might help

```
(defn calcfo [fo fi fis]
  (apply updatei fo
    (if-let [n (get @i fo)]
      [(inc (first n)), (+ fis (second n))]
      [1, fis] )))
```

Comment: this might be my favorite. really easy to read and seems the most idiomatic

Comment: It's possible to use destruction inside of `if-let`: `(if-let [[x y] (get @i fo)] [(inc x) (+ fis y)] [1 fis]`.

Comment: yes, I did this: (defn calcfo [fo fis]
  (apply updatei fo
  (if-let [[rfc rfos] (get @i fo)] ;find a previous record?
       [(inc rfc) (+ rfos fis)] ;increment the stats
       [1 fis]) ;if not then: first calc recorded
      ))

Answer (score 3):

What about using an `if` and then destructuring? Here's an approach:

```
(defn calcfo [fo fi fis]
  (let [n         (get @i fo)                                 ;find a previous record?
        [fic fos] (if n 
                    [(-> n first inc) (-> n second (+ fis))]  ;increment the stats
                    [1 fis])]                                 ;if not then: first calc recorded
      (updatei fo fic fos)))
```

The argument `fi` doesn't seem to be being used so maybe you could remove it from the argument list.

```
(defn calcfo [fo fis] ,,,)
```

The usage of `first` and `second` could also be avoided with the use of destructuring when binding `n` in the `let` form:

```
(defn calcfo [fo fis]
  (let [[x y & _]  (get @i fo)
        [fic fos]  (if x [(inc x) (+ fis y)] [1 fis])]
    (updatei fo fic fos)))
```

Comment: this is a great idea, let me try it out

Comment: Way are you using `(or (and x res1) res2)` instead of `(if x res1 res2)`? I mean, you're reimplementing `if` in your code.

Comment: I'm curious why 'and x' is required, I don't understand that. I tried it out and it works with it, but not sure how to read it. I wrote my function as this, so replace x with rfc (recorded file count): (defn calcfo [fo fis]
  (let [[rfc rfos] (get @i fo) ;find a previous record?
       [fic fos] (or 
                  (and rfc [(inc rfc) (+ rfos fis)]) ;increment the stats
                  [1 fis])] ;if not then: first calc recorded
      (updatei fo fic fos)))

Comment: @scape The `and` checks that all its arguments are not falsey (`false` or `nil`) and returns the last one of those if they all are, or the first one that's falsey. As Leonid pointed out, in this case, using `and` and `or` is like re-implementing `if`, since there's really only two possible results that depend on a single value, `x`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you would sidestep the whole problem and make your code better if you rewrote `updatei`, something like:

```
 (defn- safe+ [a b]
   (if a (if b (+ a b) a) b))
 (defn updatei [n fic fos]
   (swap! i update-in [(keyword n)] #(vector (safe+ fic (first %)) (safe+ fos (second %)))))
```

There may be a better way to write that code, but the basic idea is to use `update-in` to either store the new values (if nothing was stored for that key before), or combine them with what is already there.

Comment: You can simplify your update function by using `mapv` and `partial` instead of `#()` macro: `(partial mapv safe+ [fic fos]))`.

Comment: Interesting idea, I like the hashset; let me see how this works out

Comment: Just realized that `mapv` wont be able to handle initial `nil` value of a key. But `fnil` solves it: `(fnil (partial mapv safe+ [fic fos]) [0 0])`. In this case you don't need `safe+` either.

Comment: @LeonidBeschastny, why don't you go ahead and edit the code to make it better? I was really just trying to demonstrate the use of `update-in`.